# XML Schema Definition Tool not generating SchemaLocation

Tags: xml, poco, xsd.exe

Does the xsd.exe tool provided with Visual Studio generate the SchemaLocation attribute (in the xs:import) when generating XSDs from plain old C# objects?

I am finding that my XSDs that were generated are not valid because the xs:import will import a namespace and not provide the relative schemalocation value prompting the below

> Imported Schema for namespace 'urn:company-event-namespace' was not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found, it does not generate that attribute. This may have to do with the fact that it would not use that attribute if the attribute were present in a schema it was reading.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408336/xmlserialization-and-xsischemalocation-xsd-exe/1408387#1408387) you can add manually add an attribute.
Because the xsd tool generates a partial class, you can add this attribute in a seperate file, so you don't have to modify a generated file.

```
public partial class Gpx
{
    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string xsiSchemaLocation = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 " +
                                 "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd";
}
```