# Bind any XML & XSD to DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, xsd

I have a DataGridView which I populate with data from an XML using XmlSerializer  and a class that is used for serialization.I validate the xml using an XML schema.
I was wondering if there is a way to bind any xml with a gridview without the need to use the extra class for serialization.
I would like to be able to feed the application an XML and a XSD schema for validation and the  aplication would fill the DataGridView automatically, no matter what xml it would receive, how could I achieve this?
*The XML file should be [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521840/xml-not-matching-xsd-and-further-verification-of-attributes).

Comment: One way or another a bespoke class is in the cards.  But to help refine this question, is the binding meant to be one-time only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read XML using XDocument or XmlDocument class - to get all values. 
Problem is, that you first have to specify datagridview columns, so first you have to read whole xml to get all elements it contains and then decide which one would you like to show in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
 IEnumerable<string> dataSrc= (from ds in XDocument.Load(@"pathOfYourXMLFile").Descendants("TagName")                                          
 where ds.Element("elementName").Value == env                                       
select ds.Attribute("NameOfAttribute").Value);
```