# Simple XML Framework - Adding XSI Location in JAVA

Tags: simple-framework

**Issue:** No annotation provided for adding XSI location to root. Another stackoverflow question detailed the same problem but in C#. I'm not quite sure how to covert that over to JAVA. I need to update XML in a flat file and thought of just using string manipulation to add the XSI locations but I was hoping there might be a cleaner approach.

**Reference Question:** [C# Stackoverflow Same Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809868/how-to-add-xsi-schemalocation-to-root-c-object-xmlserializer)

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:MySample xmlns:ns0="someurl" xsi:schemaLocation="someOtherurl">
<othertag/>
</ns0:MySample>
```

Comment: Was wondering the same thing...

Comment: Ya I never figured it out. I switched back to dom parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Since it the schemaLocation is an attribute and not a namespace you can simply parse it using @Attribute annotation.

```
@Attribute
private String schemaLocation;
```

Do not forget to declare the Namespace of the root element:

```
@Namespace(prefix="xsi", reference="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
```

This worked just fine for me.