# Adjusting C# class attributes to produce right XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, schema

I have C# class with this header

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class FIXML
```

which produces XML like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <FIXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="https://www.finacle.com/fixml">
```

Problem is I need to have different header, with custom schemalocation and encoding. 
**Which attribute I can use to produce this output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FIXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml executeFinacleScript.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" >
```

Comment: not sure how you serialize, but you can config that with the xmlwritersettings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=net-6.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809868/how-to-add-xsi-schemalocation-to-root-c-object-xmlserializer will help you with the schema location