# Preserve Xml Xsd schemaLocation when deserializing then serializing

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I am deserializing an Xml file into a .NET class, modifying properties, then serializing back into the same file. This is the .NET model (vb.net)

```vb
<XmlRoot("StationSetpoints")>
Public Class XmlStationSetpoints
    <XmlElement("Setpoint")>
    Public Property Setpoints As List(Of XmlStationSetpointsSetpoint)
End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class XmlStationSetpointsSetpoint
    <XmlElement("Point")>
    Public Property Points As List(Of XmlStationSetpointsSetpointPoint)
    ' etc...
End Class
```

Deserialization and serialization (c#)

```cs
var settings = New XmlStationSetpoints();
var serializer = New XmlSerializer(XmlStationSetpoints);
// deserialize
using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)
    settings = (XmlStationSetpoints)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
// serialize
using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false)
    serializer.Serialize(sw, settings);
```

The original Xml file, including my local schema file which resides next to the Xml file `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com StationSetpoints.xsd"` (line 5)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StationSetpoints
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com StationSetpoints.xsd">
  <Setpoint PartNumber="108022">
    <Point InstrumentName="PD Stage" Value="10"/>
  </Setpoint>
  <Setpoint PartNumber="107983">
    <Point Order="2" InstrumentName="PD Stage" Value="7.5"/>
  </Setpoint>
</StationSetpoints>
```

When the file is serialized, that schema path is not included

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StationSetpoints 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Setpoint PartNumber="108022">
    <Point Order="0" InstrumentName="PD Stage" Value="10"></Point>
  </Setpoint>
  <Setpoint PartNumber="107983">
    <Point Order="2" InstrumentName="PD Stage" Value="7.5"></Point>
  </Setpoint>
</StationSetpoints>
```

How can I preserve that schema path in the .NET class, so that the serialized file includes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize and re-serialize the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute by adding an explicit property for that purpose, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408387/3744182) by [dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76217/dtb) to *[XmlSerialization and xsi:SchemaLocation (xsd.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408336/3744182)*, suitably translated to VB.NET:

```
Public Partial Class XmlStationSetpoints
    <XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace:="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")>
    Public Property xsiSchemaLocation As String = "http://www.w3schools.com StationSetpoints.xsd"
End Class
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OhcNri).

If you would like to *hardcode* the value of `xsi:schemaLocation` and have it appear unconditionally when serializing, you may do so with an explicitly implemented property like so:

```
Public Partial Class XmlStationSetpoints
    <XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace:="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")>
    Public Property xsiSchemaLocation() As String
        Get
            Return "http://www.w3schools.com StationSetpoints.xsd"
        End Get
        Set
            ' Do nothing, it's hardcoded.  A setter is required because XmlSerializer will only serialize properties with public getters and setters.
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDi59L).

And if you would like to hardcode the value of `xsi:schemaLocation` but control whether or not it appears (because e.g. it should only appear when `XmlStationSetpoints` is the root element of the XML file) you may do so with an [`xsiSchemaLocationSpecified`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842985/3744182) property like so:

```
Public Partial Class XmlStationSetpoints
    <XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace:="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")>
    Public Property xsiSchemaLocation() As String
        Get
            Return "http://www.w3schools.com StationSetpoints.xsd"
        End Get
        Set
            ' Do nothing, it's hardcoded.  A setter is required because XmlSerializer will only serialize properties with public getters and setters.
        End Set
    End Property
    <XmlIgnore>
    Public Property xsiSchemaLocationSpecified() As Boolean
End Class
```

The property will capture whether the `xsi:schemaLocation` property was encountered during deserialization, and will control whether the property is emitted during serialization.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDi59L).